# Display mail and profile photo via Microsoft Graph and PHP

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

Am working with Microsoft Graph. When user signs in, I am able to read all the users data via the code below:

```php
<?php 
session_start();
echo $acc= $_SESSION['access_token'];

echo '<br>display<br>';

echo $_SESSION['preferred_username'];
echo    $_SESSION['given_name'];

$curl = curl_init();    
curl_setopt_array($curl, array( 

CURLOPT_URL => "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",     
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", 
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30, 
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, 
//CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET", 
//CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "$data", 
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( 
"authorization: Bearer $acc"
), 
));

$response = curl_exec($curl); 
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

print_r($response);
$json = json_decode($response);

if ($err) { 
echo "cURL Error #:" . $err; 
} else { 
//echo $response; 
}

?>
```

Now I want to access login users profile photos and emails by changing the API connection links to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/` and `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages` respectively.

For retrieving the logged in Users profile photo, I am getting this error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "GetUserPhoto",
        "message": "The operation is not supported.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "78f2f57f-e256-459e-b515-1adb17cf3b2d",
            "date": "2017-11-27T03:22:09"
        }
    }
}
```

When retrieving the user's messages, I am getting this error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "d5baf587-d08f-47c2-8c2d-160536d36eb6",
            "date": "2017-11-27T04:16:15"
        }
    }
}
```

Please what could be the problem. Thanks

Comment: What kinds of account is this (AAD/MSA)? Are you sure there is a mailbox available (i.e. you can access it via Outlook for the web)?

Comment: I think its in MSA(Microsoft Account) as my email is already existing in outlook eg example@outlook.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot retrieve a profile photo from personal accounts with the current version of Microsoft Graph. Per the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_get):

> **Note** This operation in version 1.0 supports only a user's work or school mailboxes and not personal mailboxes.

Comment: At Marc LaFleur, Okay since am building app that leverages microsoft 365 API, how do I create an MSA outlook Mail account for either Users works or school which is not personal

Comment: There isn't a "microsoft 365 API", nor is there an "MSA outlook mail" for work/school. A Microsoft Account (aka MSA, Hotmail, Xbox Live or Outlook.com account) is a consumer/personal account. These are different from an Azure AD account for Work/School accounts.